# SSRS Data-Driven Subscription - How to implement audit/logging

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently implementing a number of SSRS reports (using 2014 version) with data-driven subscriptions.

There is a requirement to store information of which email addresses the reports get sent to every time the job runs, along with the parameters used.

While I can get some useful info, e.g. execution start and end time, parameters, etc. from ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog2 view, I can't find anywhere in the DB which store the email addresses' metadata.

Can anyone think of a way I can get this info and fulfill the requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExtensionSettings` field in the `Subscriptions` table in the `ReportServer` database has the information you seek. The only down part, it is all in XML. But, you can pull email addresses, and everything else about the subscription from that. Below is an example query, one I use often when looking for, or troubleshooting, subscriptions.

```
SELECT A.SubscriptionID, A.Report_OID, B.Name, [Path], 
A.LastRunTime, A.Description, C.UserName AS Owner, A.LastStatus, A.ExtensionSettings
FROM Subscriptions A INNER JOIN Catalog B
ON A.Report_OID = B.ItemID
INNER JOIN Users C
ON A.OwnerID = C.UserID
WHERE A.ExtensionSettings LIKE '%username@domain.com%'
ORDER BY A.LastRunTime DESC
```

Caveat, this works great for regular subscriptions... data-driven subscriptions have some data in this field, but not much, because the who and what of a DDS can vary from run to run.

My suggestion for data-driven subscriptions would be to add some auditing code to the query you use to drive the subscription's data. If the query isn’t already, make it a stored procedure, and add some logging in it to capture what is about to happen. Assume success in the subscription delivery.

If you are doing a number of these, as you mention, perhaps build a logging/auditing stored procedure that you pass information to and have it do the logging. If you have data sources on various machines for these, you could centralize the logging on one server and use linked servers to call the procedure. Some DBAs may balk at that, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the same thought as yours but unfortunately the requirement is to audit what and where (which email addresses) the alerts got sent to, so at execution time, not just before and assume success in the subscription delivery. Is this even possible? Or SSRS limitation?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that with SSRS and a report subscription, right out of the box. Perhaps there is a way to audit it at the email server? One other possibility, write the report results to the file system and use a SQL Agent job to email the them as attachments. Audit the send in the job. Not pretty, possible maintenance nightmare, but it will satisfy the requirement.

Comment: I know this is very old. I too am looking for an answer to this.

What I have done for now is to update my own log table that saves the rows generated by the proc that is feeding the subscription. I know if doesn't actually tell me that the email was sent but at least I know the email addresses configured at runtime. Alright, off to more searches.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I implemented a work-around similar to R.Richards' answer and John's comment on R. Richards' answer. It's working pretty nicely, so I thought I would share for others who come across this.

**Step 1: Add two hidden parameters to the report (ExecutionGUID and LogID)**

*ExecutionGUID*: Identifies a unique "batch" of records. Every record in the data-driven query will contain the same value

*LogID*: Identifies a unique render of the report from the data-driven query. Each record in the data-driven query will contain a unique value.

When the report gets run, the parameter values are logged in the dbo.ExecutionLog3 view, in the Parameters column like so:

```
ExecutionGUID=1A3C55F1-0B14-46C1-AF5F-008A3617A0F3&LogID=141
```

These can be parsed out to tie this record to the log table below.

**Step 2: Change the data-driven query to be a procedure**

Before I had something like this as the query:

```
select
    ToEmails
   ,CcEmails
   ,EmailSubject
   ,Param1
   ,Param2
from
    mytable
```

Then I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataDrivenSubscriptionLog](
    [LogID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ExecutionGUID] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [ToEmails] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [CcEmails] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [EmailSubject] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Param1] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Param2] [varchar](250) NULL
)
```

And changed my procedure to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDataDrivenDataSet
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @ExecutionGUID varchar(36)

    set @ExecutionGUID = NEWID()

    insert into dbo.DataDrivenSubscriptionLog
    select
        GETDATE() as LogDateTime
        ,@ExecutionGUID as ExecutionGUID
        ,ToEmails
        ,CcEmails
        ,EmailSubject
        ,Param1
        ,Param2
    from
        mytable

    select
        *
    from
        dbo.DataDrivenSubscriptionLog
    where
        ExecutionGUID = @ExecutionGUID

END
```

**Step 3: Update the data driven subscription to use the proc and map the hidden columns**

This is where it all ties together. The subscription will run the procedure, which adds the records to the log and returns the values in that batch from the log. This result set is then mapped into the email information and the parameters, including the hidden parameters of ExecutionGUID and LogID.

Once the subscription runs, the log table and the ExecutionLog3 view can be joined together. You'll be able to know which records should have run but didn't, which records did run, and who the reports were sent to.